# Flash Player Version Problem

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3, flash

I am facing one weird problem. In my flex application, there is one
grid on click of each grid item, it will dispatch one event and show
the details. As usual am changing the state of the component to
achieve this. But this is working perfectly in my machine, but from my
client side it is not working. Only difference am seeing is the
difference in flash player version. The FP version am having here is
10,0,45,2 but the onsite is having the latest version : 10.1.102.64.
Will this cause any problem in the behaviour of the flex application?
Am quite confused here, because I have no rights to change the player
version in my machine.

Do anyone have face the same problem like this. Or can anyone help me
with the main difference between these two versions.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Cheers,
Anoop

Comment: version 10.1 release notes : http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/838/cpsid_83808.html did you try to downgrade that latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Most behavioral differences between flex applications are due to different flex SDKs being used during compilation (for instance, is your client viewing the binary-exact copy of the .swf file that you are running) or browsers with different plug-in APIs (the way they handle 500 errors for instance). If you think it's a flash player version issue (they are probably rare since they run regression tests across player builds so that flash swf files from eons ago run fine), you can certainly upgrade to that player build and see for yourself.

Are you also able to rule-out any connectivity issues such as firewalls or proxy servers?

Answer (score 0):

While the item is clicked what are you using you using to get the selected item - event.target.selecteditem or event.currentTaget.selecteditem  ? Try to change from target to currentTarget or vice-versa,it might work in both the machines.